# The program always displays 0 matches even if some numbers match

Tags: c++, function

> The program should have an array of five integers named lottery and should generate a random number in the range of 0 through 9 for each element in the array.
>
> The user should enter five digits which should be stored in an integer array named user.
>
> The program is to compare the corresponding elements in the two arrays and keep a count of the digits that match. For example, the following shows the lottery array and the user array with sample numbers stored in each. The program should display the random numbers stored in the lottery array and the number of matching digits.
>
> If all the digits match, display a message proclaiming the user as a grand prize winner. If the player got only three matches, have them guess a number between 1 and 20 based on a randomly generated number. If they guess the correct number in two tries, they will be awarded a cash prize of $500. Otherwise, they should be encouraged to purchase another ticket next time.

Code:

```
#include <iostream> // for cin and cout streams
#include <cstdlib>  // for the rand and srand functions
#include <ctime>    // for the time function



// Constant Declarations
// ---------------------

const int lotteryDigits = 9;
const int SIZE = 5;



// Function Prototypes
// -------------------

void generateLottery(int[], int, int);
void userInput(int[], int);
int matchCounter(int[], int[], int);
void displayNumbers(int[], int[]);
void winnerOrLoser(int);



// -------------
// Main Function
// -------------



using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Variable Declarations
    int lottery[5] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    int user[5] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    int matches = 0;

    //Function Calls
    generateLottery(lottery, SIZE, lotteryDigits);

    userInput(user, SIZE);

    matches = matchCounter(lottery, user, matches);


    displayNumbers(lottery, user);

    winnerOrLoser(matches);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
} //end main



// --------------------
// Function Definitions
// --------------------



// Randomly generates winning lottery numbers

void generateLottery(int lottery[], int, int)
{
    unsigned seed = time(0);
    srand(seed);

    for (int count=0; count<SIZE; count++)
    {
        lottery[count] = 1 + rand() % lotteryDigits;
    }
} // end generateLottery


// Reads user lottery number choices

void userInput(int user[], int)
{
    cout << "This program will simulate a lottery.\n\n";

    for (int count1=0; count1<SIZE; count1++)
    {
        cout << "Enter a digit between 0 and 9: ";
        cin >> user[count1];

        while (user[count1]<0 || user[count1]>9)
        {
            cout << "Error! Entry must be between 0 and 9: ";
            cin >> user[count1];
        }
    }
} // end userInput



// Counts the number of matches

int matchCounter(int lotto[], int input[], int match)
{
    bool numMatch = true;

    for (int check = 0; check <= SIZE; check++)
    {
        if (lotto[check] != input[check])
            numMatch = false;
        check++;
    }

    return match;
} // end matchCounter



// Diplays the winning numbers and the user's numbers

void displayNumbers(int lottery[], int user[])
{
    cout << "\nThe winning lottery numbers are: " << lottery[0] << " " << lottery[1] << " " << lottery[2] << " " << lottery[3] << " " << lottery[4] << endl;
    cout << "Your lottery numbers are: " << user[0] << " " << user[1] << " " << user[2] << " " << user[3] << " " << user[4] << endl;
} // end displayNumbers



//Displays the number of matches and whether or not the user has won

void winnerOrLoser(int matches)
{
    cout << "You matched " << matches << " numbers";

    if (matches == SIZE)
        cout << "grand prize winner\n";
    else if (matches==3)
        cout << "";

} // end winnerOrLoser
```

Comment: "Hello I'm getting 0" is not a technical description of a problem which is what your title should focus on. Additionally the giant chunk of words above the code is not really that easy to understand, and the code is likewise a whole lot of blank lines and other stuff that impedes understanding of it.

Comment: Tip: In C++ use `std::vector` and pass this as a mutable (reference) argument if necessary, or return it as the result of a function. Try to avoid C-style arrays and depending on array-to-pointer decay.

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: One of the best ways to find a bug is to remove everything that isn't the bug and see what's left. This is remarkably effective in handling code that has multiple bugs since bugs have an annoying tendency to team up with one another. Isolate the bugs and kill them one at t a time. Use [mre] as inspiration.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your program always display 0 digit match because `matchCounter` function works wrong. you can write like this.

```
int matchCounter(int lotto[], int input[], int match) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) 
    {
        if (lotto[i] == input[i])
           ++match;
    }
    return match;
}
```

You can also pass `match` by reference to make your program faster.
This is full your code that I have fixed rely on your question:

```
#include <cstdlib>      // for the rand and srand functions
#include <ctime>        // for the time function
#include <iostream>     // for cin and cout streams
using namespace std;

// Constant Declarations
// ---------------------
const int lotteryDigits = 9;
const int SIZE = 5;


// Randomly generates winning lottery numbers
void generateLottery(int lottery[]) {
    srand(time(0));

    for (int count = 0; count < SIZE; count++) 
        lottery[count] = rand() % (lotteryDigits + 1); // to get digits from 0 -> 9
}


// Reads user lottery number choices
void userInput(int user[]) {
    cout << "This program will simulate a lottery.\n\n";
    for (int count = 0; count < SIZE; ++count) {
         cout << "Enter a digit between 0 and 9: ";
         cin >> user[count];

         while (user[count] < 0 || user[count] > 9) {
               cout << "Error! Entry must be between 0 and 9: ";
               cin >> user[count];
         }
    }
}


// Counts the number of matches
int matchCounter(int lotto[], int input[]) {
    int match = 0;
    for (int check = 0; check < SIZE; check++) 
        if (lotto[check] == input[check])
           ++match;
    return match;
}


// Diplays the winning numbers and the user's numbers
void displayNumbers(int lottery[], int user[]) {
    cout << "\nThe winning lottery numbers are: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
        cout << lottery[i] << " ";

    cout << "\nYour lottery numbers are: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
        cout << user[i] << " ";
}


// Displays the number of matches and whether or not the user has won
void winnerOrLoser(int matches) {
    cout << "You matched " << matches << " numbers";

    if (matches == SIZE)
        cout << "grand prize winner\n";
    else if (matches == 3)
        cout << "";

}


// -------------
// Main Function
// -------------

int main() {
    // Variable Declarations
    int lottery[5];
    int user[5];
    int matches = 0;

    //Function Calls
    generateLottery(lottery);
    userInput(user);
    
    matches = matchCounter(lottery, user);
    displayNumbers(lottery, user);
    winnerOrLoser(matches);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm still not getting the correct amount of matches

Comment: help me with the last part of my question please.\

Comment: I will write my answer for you again with full code fixed.